# Ruby on Rails. Ассоциации в шаблоне

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть форма(файл "_form.html.erb"):

```
<%= form_with(model: product) do |form| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% product.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :city_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :city_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :shop_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :shop_id %>
  </div>
```

Модели:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

Как заменить shop_id на name из связанной таблицы shops?

Comment: Сделать селект со списком возможных магазинов, в котором лейблами будут их названия, а значениями - айдишники

Comment: зачем здесь селект? Нужно вместо id дернуть name из связанной таблицы

Comment: И куда вы будете его сохранять?

Comment: в таблицу products - в поле shop_id

Comment: Вы туда сможете сохранить только shop_id, а не name. Самый простой способ решения проблемы - это селект, о котором я писала выше. Иначе вам придётся писать кастомную логику обработки формы - берем поле name, ищем по нему магазин, в модельку сохраняем его айдишник, а если не нашли, то выводим ошибку валидации

Comment: Знаю, что shop_id. Добавил <% product.shops.each do |s| %> в шаблон - выдает ошибку "undefined method `shops' for #<Product id: 1..."(NoMethodError in Products#edit)

Comment: Полагаю, у вас не указана связь между моделями? Добавьте код моделей к вопросу

Comment: Добавил. Извините, что так долго - был занят

Comment: Невнимательно предыдущий ваш коммент прочла. Продукт у вас принадлежит к магазину, то есть у продукта один магазин. Что вы хотели сделать через `product.shops.each do`?

Comment: вывести список всех магазинов: <li><%= s.name %></li>, чтобы из него можно было выбрать нужный

Comment: Тогда `Shop.all.each do`

Comment: Спасибо. А чем Shop.all.each отличается от Shops.each?

Comment: Тем, что `Shop.all` даёт вам всё существующие в БД магазины и вы можете их итерировать, а `product.shops` даёт ошибку, потому как продукт приналежит только к одному магазину